# A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

When I try to compile using

ionic cordova build --release android

I get the following error message...What might be the reason..

```js
BUILD FAILED in 0s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: mips64el-linux-android

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova build android --release exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: is this the first time your trying to build in this machine?

Comment: Yes.. It is working in other system.. Through git we pulled in another system and facing this issue..

Comment: then i suggest you to check that NDK tools installed properly or not, if your not using NDK tools in your app try to remove and then try for build

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what version of the Android NDK you are using. The suppport for MIPS and MIPS64 abis was stopped in NDK r17 (see [Android NDK official documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis)). This is because MIPS-based Android devices are completely obsolete. You need to use NDK r16 or older for it to work. You can download older NDK releases [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases). Alternativeley, as suggested [here](https://support.wikitude.com/support/discussions/topics/5000089047), you can just copy the corresponding directories from the NDK r17 (or older) in the r18 ndk-bundle/toolchains. The ones in the r17 are actually empty with a little notice that says that the directories were left there for compatibility. This last option is what I have done and it worked for me.

Comment: This saved me after two days of head scratching, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its the problem with NDK tool chains file missing in NDK bundle, to resolve this issue make sure you properly install the NDK bundle, still if you cant fine try to download externally and place in the right path.

If your not using NDK tools for your app you can remove the entire folder of NDk and it will work fine with a warning  message that NDK tools files missed